# I want to create arrays within arrays and enter data in them

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to create arrays within arrays and then fill them up using a function.
I have some code written for this below but I am unable to append them inside each other.

**I want to create array in the following format:**

```
array (
            0 =>
                array (
                    'name' => 'Shopping and fashion',
                    'id' => '0',
                    'type' => 'Interests',
                    'childNodes' =>
                        array (
                            0 =>
                                array (
                                    'name' => 'Beauty',
                                    'id' => '6002867432822',
                                    'parentName' => 'Shopping and fashion',
                                    'childNodes' =>
                                        array (
                                            0 =>
                                                array (
                                                    'name' => 'Cosmetics',
                                                    'id' => '6002839660079',
                                                    'parentName' => 'Beauty',
                                                ),
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
);
```

Code I have:

```
    for ($i = $depth - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
        #hierarchy here

        $my_array = ['name' =>$pagepaths[$i],
                'id' => $pageid];
        $toAdd = [ $my_array => $toAdd,];
        }
```

My input Data:

```
array(
   'id' => '6002839660079',
   'name' => 'Cosmetics',
   'type' => 'interests',
   'path' => 
  array (
    0 => 'Shopping and fashion',
    1 => 'Beauty',
    2 => 'Cosmetics',
  ),
   'audience_size' => 1122219840,
   'lifecycle' => 2,
)
```

I am creating arrays starting from the child array, i.e Cosmetics in the example above.
My code logic is to create the inner most array and then append them inside another array.
However the values from $myarray aren't appending to $toAdd.
My code is a work in progress so I haven't yet added the "ParentName" part to it yet.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share your input data, i.e. the data holding the parent-child relationships?

Comment: I smell recursion

Comment: I have added my input array . The hierarchy of arrays is based on the array which has "Shopping and fashion", "Beauty" and "Cosmetics" in it.@metad00r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a way to map your data like a tree data structure. It's not a good idea to use array for this, since a tree is a recursive data structure. Please don't use arrays for recursive data structures. Much easier and more elegant is an object oriented approach. Write a class that represents your data structure:

```
class Category
{
    private $id;

    private $name;

    private $parent;

    private $children;

    public function __construct(int $id, string $name, ?Category $parent = null)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->parent = $parent;
        $this->children = [];
    }

    public function getId(): int { return $this->id; }
    public function setId(int $id): void { $this->id = $id; }

    public function getName(): string { return $this->name; }
    public function setName(string $name): void { $this->name = $name; }

    public function getParent(): ?Category { return $this->parent; }
    public function setParent(Category $parent): void { $this->parent = $parent; }

    public function getChildren(): array { return $this->children; }
    public function addChild(Category $child): void 
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
        $child->setParent($this);
    }
}
```

Use this class to build your data:

```
$shoppingAndFashion = new Category(1, 'Shopping and fashion');
$beauty = new Category(6002867432822, 'Beauty');
$beauty->addChild(new Category(6002839660079, 'Cosmetics'));
$beauty->addChild(new Category(6002839660080, 'Nail files'));
$shoppingAndFashion->addChild($beauty);
```

It's also easy to travers this structure:

```
function traversal(Category $category) 
{
    echo '<li>' . $category->getId() . ': ' . $category->getName();
    if (!empty($category->getChildren())) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($category->getChildren() as $child) {
            traversal($child);
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
}

echo '<ul>';
traversal($shoppingAndFashion);
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code does exactly what I want it to do. The only problem I am facing it is the variable $shoppingAndFashion is of type object and typecasting it into array messes the formatting in it

Comment: For which purpose you need the array? You can do everything with this object oriented tree structure.

Comment: I need to give this array to the UI team. They have specifically requested me to send this to them in the format I mentioned above. Sorry to bother you with this and thank you for the help